# Shortcode for custom query not returning results when attributes are added

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, query

I'm trying to build a shortcode that will allow the user to choose what category is displayed and how many posts will show. The shortcode worked fine until I added the 'tax_query'

```
add_shortcode( 'latest_post', 'latest_post_query_shortcode' );
function latest_post_query_shortcode(  $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'post_per_page' => '',
            'category' => '',
    ), $atts );

    $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=> 3,
            'tax_query'     => array( array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                'field'     => 'slug',
                                'terms'     => $categories
                            ), ),
        );

        $string = '';
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <section class="recent-posts clear">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'left' ); ?>>
                <? echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">';
                    echo get_the_title( $_post->ID);
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">';
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID, 'medium' );
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">';
                    echo '<button>Read More</button>';
                    echo '</a>';
                ?>

            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section>
    <?php } else {
        echo 'No posts found';
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Before adding the tax_query, it would show the three latest posts, with the tax_query, it just shows "No posts found." What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I used shortcode_atts but should `$categories` be `$category`? also, make sure it's returning the correct type e.g. string or int and you're searching for a valid slug.

Comment: I tried that (category vs categories), thinking the same thing but unfortunately it wasn't it. The slugs I've tested are valid. How would I check what it's supposed to be returning?

Comment: If you're passing a slug then it should be fine, it's more if you were passing an id where it would probably be a string instead of an int but basically do a `var_dump($categories) ` right before the `$args = array( ...` so that you can see what it's value is. It would also be worth sharing the shortcode you're using to test this.

Comment: I'm getting NULL from the var_dump. Shortcode is:
[latest_post category="drinks"] 31 posts under the "drinks" slug https://imgur.com/EyvJSEH

Comment: Should definitely say `$category` then, what do you get if you var_dump($category);?

Comment: Hmm, still null

Comment: My mistake it's been a while since I've done this, you need to use `$atts['category']` so `var_dump($atts['category']);` or in your tax_query `'terms' => $atts['category']` if you want to just us `$category` you need to `wrap shortcode_atts` in an `extract` so something like `extract(shortcode_atts(array( ... ), $atts));` what does that give you?

Comment: No problem, I appreciate you trying to help. So changing the var dump to ($atts['category']) gives me 
`string(6) "drinks"`
Then still echoes my else of "no posts found"
Interestingly, the only thing I can get to work is "extract" but everyone EMPHATICALLY says not to use that as it's dated. :/

Comment: I've replicated this setup locally (same category name etc) and your code now works for me, the only issue I had was where you used the shorthand PHP opening tag `<?` instead of `<?php` but as long as your server is setup to use `short_open_tag=On` it's not a problem and wouldn't result in "No posts found" the only way that would happen is if your query returns no posts. If it works when you manually type in `'term' => 'drinks'` in the tax query and `var_dump($atts['category'])` returns `string(6) "drinks"` then it should work when you use `'term' => $atts['category']` check for typos...

Comment: Thank you Bob! Switching it to $atts['category'] was it.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)